# WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, barman

I am trying to configure Barman to backup. When I do a `barman check replica` I keep getting:

```
Server replica:
WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)
PostgreSQL: OK
superuser: OK
wal_level: OK
directories: OK
retention policy settings: OK
backup maximum age: FAILED (interval provided: 1 day, latest backup age: No available backups)
compression settings: OK
failed backups: OK (there are 0 failed backups)
minimum redundancy requirements: FAILED (have 0 backups, expected at least 2)
ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
not in recovery: FAILED (cannot perform exclusive backup on a standby)
archive_mode: OK
archive_command: OK
continuous archiving: OK
archiver errors: OK
```

I am using Postgresql 9.6 and barman 2.1; I am not sure as to what the issue is could someone help?
Here is my Barman server configuration:

```
description = "Database backup"
conninfo = host=<db-ip> user=postgres dbname=db
backup_method = rsync
ssh_command = ssh postgres@<db-ip>
archiver = on
```

Comment: Look carefully at the line telling you `minimum redundancy requirements: FAILED (have 0 backups, expected at least 2)`

Comment: I am more worried about the  `WAL archive: FAILED (please make sure WAL shipping is setup)` line. The other error makes sense to me and seemed valid as I haven't setup backups yet. WAL Archive Failed error should not be coming.

Comment: What version of Barman are you using? Have you run `barman switch-xlog --force --archive <server_name>` as noted in the [barman documentation](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.1/#verification-of-wal-archiving-configuration) to verify WAL archiving is working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When running into an error like this, be sure to run `barman switch-xlog --force --archive <server_name>` as noted in the [barman documentation](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.1/#verification-of-wal-archiving-configuration) to verify the WAL archiving process.

Comment: I see a transaction log in my cluster data directory (`/pg_xlog`), but the command above fails, after the default 30 second itmeout.

Comment: @sameers You should ask a new question, and post your logs and command outputs to it.

Answer (score 2):

### in brief

Barman's `incoming_wals_directory` and Postgresql.conf's `archive_command` not matched as described in details [here](https://github.com/namgivu/devops-barman-start/blob/master/doc/zz.aftermath-check.md#troubleshooter-for-03---error-wal-archive-failed-please-make-sure-wal-shipping-is-setup)

### details

Another cause is that the **not matched** between

- Barman's `incoming_wals_directory`
- Postgresql.conf's `archive_command`

Bash util to check

```
barman@backup $ barman show-server pg | grep incoming_wals_directory
# output1
# > incoming_wals_directory: /var/lib/barman/pg/incoming

postgres@pg $ cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf | grep archive_command
# output2
# > archive_command = 'rsync -a  %p  barman@staging:/var/lib/barman/pg/incoming/%f'
```

We **must have same path** in :output1 and :output2

Make them matched if they don't and don't forget to restart postgres afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Use `barman switch-wal SERVER --force --archive --archive-timeout 30`.

For streaming archiving, you should also manually execute `barman cron` to bring up `receive-wal`. Otherwise, you need to wait at least 1 min for the cron to take effect automatically, while the `switch-wal` command waits only for 30 seconds by default, and then fails.

Comment: `barman cron` saved the day...thank you!!!